# How can I deal with each adjoin two element difference greater than threshold from Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a problem with Spark Scala which get the value of each adjoin two element difference greater than threshold,I create a new RDD like this:

```
  [2,3,5,8,19,3,5,89,20,17]
```

I want to subtract each two adjoin element like this:

```
 a.apply(1)-a.apply(0) ,a.apply(2)-a.apply(1),…… a.apply(a.lenght)-a.apply(a.lenght-1)
```

If the result greater than the threshold of 10,than output the collection,like this:

```
[19,89]
```

How can I do this with scala from RDD?

Comment: what is the complete output of above RDD? is it only [19,89]??

Comment: Yes,3-2=1,5-3=2,8-5=3,19-8=11,3-19=-13,5-3=2,89-5=84,20-89=-69,17-20=-3, so 19-8=11 and 89-5=84, only this two result greater than 10, the result RDD is [19,89]

Comment: what is the size of your rdd ?

Comment: one month data from GPS coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data as

```
val data = Seq(2,3,5,8,19,3,5,89,20,17)
```

you can create rdd as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
```

What you desire can be achieved by doing the following

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
 val finalrdd = rdd
                  .sliding(2)
                  .map(x => (x(1), x(1)-x(0)))
                  .filter(y => y._2 > 10)
                  .map(z => z._1)
```

Doing

```
finalrdd.foreach(println)
```

should print

```
19
89
```

Comment: Is the `mllib` import really required? `sliding` is a scala feature.

Comment: Yes @philantrovert, the import is needed. scala sliding feature doesn't work in rdd.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another RDD from the original dataframe and zip those two RDD which creates a tuple like (2,3)(3,5)(5,8) and filter the subtracted result if it is greater than 10

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(2,3,5,8,19,3,5,89,20,17))

val first = rdd.first()
rdd.zip(rdd.filter(r => r != first))
  .map( k => ((k._2 - k._1), k._2))
  .filter(k => k._1 > 10 )
  .map(t => t._2).foreach(println)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That filters out all rows that happen to equal the first. That might or might not work for the OP.

Comment: Oh yes @TheArchetypalPaul I did not notice it